# Convert a 2D list into a string

Tags: string, python-3.x, list

I want to convert a 2D list into a string with /n after each line:
My current problem is, that my list is in a list and I don't know how to handle that.
For example:

[image: my list in list]

should be converted to a string with only spaces and X and /n.
I am trying to solve this problem since 2 hours and I get fix that.

Comment: please do not post images; post your code! [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not helpful. and `''.join(line for line in area)` might get you a little closer to the solution of your problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want:

```
# Just used this to check the output
import pprint

# generating your input matrix to test with.
input_array = [[' ' for i in range(0,10)] for j in range(0,10)]

input_array[1][2:7] = ['X']*5
pprint.pprint(input_array)


# This gets all values in one string
# ''.join(string for line_array in input_array for string in line_array)
```

To separate the strings from each line with a line return, we can do the following. This gets a string for each line, joined on "" and then join those on the line return character `\n`

```
final_answer = '\n'.join([''.join([character for character in line ]) for line in input_array])
pprint.pprint(final_answer)
```

Output:

[image]